Optimizing Leaf Concentration on a Grid with Probabilistic Dispersion Using Python
I'm working on a simulation problem where I need to strategically use a leaf blower to concentrate leaves from a square grid into a single non-edge square. The grid is divided into squares, and the leaf blower can move leaves from one square (A) to another (B), with some leaves being dispersed to adjacent squares due to the blower's imprecision.
Problem Constraints:

Basis is 2D grid with size n * n
Each square initially contains 100 leaves
When blowing from square A to B :


80% of the leaves go directly to B
10% go to the square to the left of B
10% go to the square to the right of B
10% of the leaves initially at B are blown to the square behind B


The target square (Q) cannot be an edge or corner square
The aim is to concentrate as many leaves as possible into Q using a series of directional blows

Simulation goal:
Develop a strategy to determine where the caretaker should stand and in which direction to blow in order to maximize leaf concentration in the target square.
Question:
Can anyone suggest or provide a Python algorithm that simulates this scenario and helps develop a strategy to efficiently gather as many leaves as possible into the target square? I am looking for ways to model the probabilistic nature of leaf dispersion and optimize the sequence of moves.
So far, I've attempted to simulate random moves, but the dispersion effect seems to dilute the concentration too much. I am considering a more systematic approach like pathfinding or optimization algorithms.
Any suggestions or guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!
